# "Application failed to start" after spring-boot-starter-mail usage

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, email, smtp

Want to implement simple mail sender solution based on `spring-boot-starter-mail`
After adding dependency and set up properties I tried to run app and that error occurred.
I think that's worth noticing that I am not, and not about either to implement Spring Cloud. Just the mail service. 
Doesn't understand why spring boot expects some services that are from these package.

Tried various version of dependency, defining some @Beans but don't think that's the issue

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

logs:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-10-23 00:07:05.752 ERROR 19576 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 1 of method mailNotifier in de.codecentric.boot.admin.server.config.AdminServerNotifierAutoConfiguration$MailNotifierConfiguration required a bean of type 'de.codecentric.boot.admin.server.domain.entities.InstanceRepository' that could not be found.

The following candidates were found but could not be injected:
    - Bean method 'instanceRepository' in 'AdminServerAutoConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnBean (types: de.codecentric.boot.admin.server.config.AdminServerMarkerConfiguration$Marker; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans of type de.codecentric.boot.admin.server.config.AdminServerMarkerConfiguration$Marker


Action:

Consider revisiting the entries above or defining a bean of type 'de.codecentric.boot.admin.server.domain.entities.InstanceRepository' in your configuration.
```

Just want to send email via smtp.gmail.com
Hope that `spring-boot-starter-mail` 'd be enough for that.

Thanks!

Comment: It seems that you are using other dependencies such as **Spring Boot Admin** which caused the error. And if what you want is to send mail only, I think to add `spring-boot-starter-parent`, `spring-boot-starter` and `spring-boot-starter-mail` into your POM file is enough.

Answer (score 0):

As LHCHIN commented, it was a matter of `spring-boot-admin-starter-server` and `spring-boot-admin-dependencies` in `<dependencyManagement/>`

Answer (score 0):

I would always advice to avoid copy pasting the dependencies with their version. Most of the cases you don't need to specifiy the version and let Spring boot figure out based on mvn which version will be suitable for you.

For the spring boot starter mail, I just needed the following dependencies

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.6</version>
</dependency>
```

The source I used is : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-email and it worked for me with version and without.